# Find time segments by conditions in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I have data `df`:

```
Timestamp = pd.date_range('2020-02-06 08:23:04', periods=1000, freq='s')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': Timestamp,
                   'Data': 30+15*np.cos(np.linspace(0,10,Timestamp.size))})

df['timediff'] = (df['Timestamp'].shift(-1) - df['Timestamp']).dt.total_seconds()   
df['datadiff'] = df['Data'].shift(-1) - df['Data']
df['gradient'] = df['datadiff'] / df['timediff']
```

I want to find time segments with `gradient` > 0.13. So the `start` is the first data point in this range and the `end` is the last data point in the range, do it for entire `df`.

Expected outcome:

```
Start               Start_Data  End                 End_Data
2020-02-06 08:30:50 29.284407   2020-02-06 08:30:58 30.485252
                       ...
```

Comment: Do you want a one liner code or loops work too?

Comment: It doesn't matter tbh. I do hope it could be reused if possible.

Comment: Is there anything speaking against the use of a [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), i.e. `mask = (df['gradient'] > 0.13)` and `print(df[mask])` ?

Comment: @Asmus I think there is no problem with that. But how can l create a table with the `start` and `end` time effectively?

Comment: @Ehsan Is it possible to achieve the expected outcome without a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I will proceed:

```
df['test'] = (df.gradient > 0.13).astype('int') 
# identifies changes in test condition
df["value_grp"] = (df.test.diff(1) != 0).astype("int").cumsum()

# Filter the groups with test condition being true and look at begin and end times
df.groupby('value_grp').filter(lambda x: (x.test==1).all()).Timestamp.min()
df.groupby('value_grp').filter(lambda x: (x.test==1).all()).Timestamp.max()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However it returned only `Timestamp('2020-02-06 08:30:58')`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore I like this idea. However, it does not create the output in the format you asked. Probably with few more lines you can create that output.

Comment: Why is this returning only one timestamp?